# How to go about creating a race track game?

Tags: android, drawing, java-2d

i am planning to make racing game in android.I have created many applications in different mobile technology. but i am pretty much beginner for game application. So my question is how can i make race track in android? How should i show that car is moving on that race track. 
I have the images of cars and race track. But i have no idea how should i show the part of race track and how should show that car is moving on that track??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you download [AndEngine](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/) ( an open source 2d android game develoopmnent framework ). In the [examples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/) there is a (very simple) **race track demo** with a movable car + controls + obstacles. If you have troubles you can always get support from the [forums](http://www.andengine.org/forums/)

AndEngine has a very easy learning curve :-) 

Have fun creating your racing game!!

Here are 2 good tutorials on starting with 2d:
- [Canvas tutorial](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-paint-animate-loop-and-remove-a-sprite/)
- [OpenGL tutorial](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-opengl-3d-game-development-basics/)

The **last part**, about showing only a part of the map, can be achieved by using a `BoundCamera` in AndEngine.

Comment: Hey! That's cheating! ;-) +1 though. Nice find.

Comment: :-D a good start is half the work :)

Comment: Agreed. Though some understanding of the raw drawing process doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Yeah :-) thats why i added 2 basic tutorials

Answer (score 4):

You should start with studying the [2D graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) capabilities of the Android library. Here's another good [reference article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html). It lists some drawing options including drawing to the Canvas object which is probably the right choice for the kind of game you're describing.

Here's a [full but simple example of handling the onDraw event](http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2008/11/android-graphics-example/) for a canvas and performing custom drawing. Here's a small bit of the code:

```
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(20, 20, 15, paint);
```

The above is a simple example that draws a circle with a particular size to a particular location on the canvas. It's a good place to start. To finish your game you'll be drawing bitmaps which is a more complex process but conceptually similar.