# Opengl scrolling world guidance

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm looking for a tutorial about how to implement a simple horizontally scrolling background with various objects that auto-scrolls as your character/player moves just like various car/motorbikes games.

Comment: I would recommend asking this on the GameDev Stack Overflow. Your answer might be less Android related, but they could definitely give you a good answer from a OpenGL / Game Development prospective.

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

think about it like this. 
the player is always 0/0. everything moves around the player.
so if you want a auto scroll you have to constanly increase your x coordinates of all your objects in your main loop depending on the speed you want.

Comment: Thanks for responding, had been searching myself how to go about it.  Since there would be a lot of obstacles/ objects around, will it not create memory issues if I load every thing in the beginning? Should I load objects only for the visible area? Is it advisable to use a gaming engine like andengine? Check responses to question: post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605814/how-to-go-about-creating-a-race-track-game