# Android 3d racing game,how to move the track and objects to backwards?

Tags: android

How the game objects like road side trees and rocks moving backwards while main object(bike) moving to forward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605814/how-to-go-about-creating-a-race-track-game

Comment: thanks for the replay.But it was And-engine 2d,but m looking for 3d racing game tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood you, but for me you're asking about the basics of 3D graphics. Think about the world as a collection of objects and a camera. You can move each object individually. You can also move the camera, and when you do this, it will result in entire scene moving on the screen.

Now, you should attach the camera to the bike and move them together. It will result in the bike moving across the scene, which is going to look like all the stuff is moving backwards.